# Topology on $\mathbb N$ formed by taking the open sets to be $\emptyset, \mathbb{N}$ and $\{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n \} $ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, integers

I am having some definition-wise problems.

**Problem:** Prove that we get a topology for $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \} $ by taking the open sets to be $\emptyset, \mathbb{N}$ and $\{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n \} $ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My point of confusion:** How do we show that any union of the open sets, as defined, is an open set "formally"?

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology#The_Alexandrov_topology_on_a_preordered_set).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so that the open sets are $\varnothing,\Bbb N$, and the sets $U_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a collection of open sets. If $\Bbb N\in\mathscr{U}$, then clearly $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\Bbb N$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ is open. If $\mathscr{U}=\{\varnothing\}$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\varnothing$, which is open. The only remaining possibility is that $\Bbb N\notin\mathscr{U}$, and there is at least one $U_n\in\mathscr{U}$. Let $M=\{n\in\Bbb N:U_n\in\mathscr{U}\}$.

- What is $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ if $M$ is infinite?
- If $M$ is finite, what is $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$? If you get completely stuck on this part, mouse-over the spoiler protected further hint below.

> Consider $\max M$.

Comment: I didn't know about ">!" -- cool feature(!)

Comment: @Brian: It’s a bit limited – you can use it only once in an answer, and you can’t use displayed formulae within it – but it’s still a great feature.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_n=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  For $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_k$, we have $N_{n_1}\subseteq N_{n_2}\subseteq\ldots\subseteq N_{n_k}$.  So,
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^k N_{n_j}=N_{n_k}.$$

The infinite case is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Each open set $A$ of the topology that is not $\emptyset$ or $\Bbb N$ is uniquely determined by its greatest integer member $n = \max A$. Let's write $[n] = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$.

Suppose $\mathscr{U}$ is a collection of open sets. If $\mathscr{U}$ contains $\emptyset$ we can safely omit it without affecting the union. If $\mathscr{U}$ itself is empty then its union is $\emptyset$ and therefore open. There are then three cases:

1. $\Bbb N \in \mathscr{U}$. Then clearly $\bigcup \mathscr{U} = \Bbb N$, which is open.
2. $\mathscr{U}$ is finite, not containing $\Bbb N$. Then $\mathscr{U}$ contains one largest set $[n]$, which includes all other sets in $\mathscr{U}$: if $A\in \mathscr{U}$ then $A\subseteq [n]$. Then $[n] = \bigcup \mathscr{U}$, so the union is an open set.
3. $\mathscr{U}$ is infinite, not containing $\Bbb N$. Then the set of $\max A$ for $A\in \mathscr{U}$ is unbounded, so $\bigcup \mathscr{U} = \Bbb N$, which is also an open set.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut 3 cases, I say... pulled the trigger too fast.

Comment: I'd call that an indexed family. For me, & for many, a collection of open sets is just a set of open sets — for this topology, a subset of $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$. As $\bigcup$ of an indexed family = $\bigcup$ of the  range of the indexed family, it's splitting hairs over nothing.

Comment: Ok, thank to have clarified. Yes, it's a minor question of vocabulary, but I really had *indexed family* in mind. Sorry to have insisted :-)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut No problem. If I had been talking about an indexed family, my language would have been different (and much wordier, in order to be precise: I wouldn't be able to say "if $\mathscr{U}$ contains $\emptyset$", and the like, as I'd have to mention some index set $I$ and talk about $U_i = \emptyset$ for some $i\in I$... and of course I would have written the unions differently.) My $\mathscr{U}$ is the range of the indexed family you had in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Call a subset $S$ of an ordered set $X$ 'downward closed' if $\forall a\in S, \forall b\in X, b<a \implies b\in S$. Now, it is an easy exercise to check that

- The collection of all downward closed sets forms a topology on $X$. (It is infact closed under arbitrary intersections.)
- The collection of sets in the given problem is precisely the collection of downward closed sets in the case $X=\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathcal O$ to be a set of "open" sets as described. Then, proceed by cases:

- What is $\bigcup\mathcal O$ if $\mathcal O=\emptyset$?
- What is $\bigcup\mathcal O$ if $\mathcal O$ has a single element?
- What is $\bigcup\mathcal O$ if $\Bbb N\in\mathcal O$?
- What is $\bigcup\mathcal O$ if $\mathcal O$ is finite with more than one element, and $\Bbb N\notin\mathcal O$?
- What is $\bigcup\mathcal O$ if $\mathcal O$ is infinite?

Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Denote $[n] := \{1,2,...,n\}$. Denote $U$ as variable for open set

Case 0: $\bigcup U_i = \bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing$, hence open. so for nonempty unions:

Case 1: $\bigcup U_i$ contains $U_j = \mathbb{N}$, then union is $\mathbb{N}$, hence open.

Case 2: $\bigcup U_i$ does not contains $U_j = \mathbb{N}$, so rewrite it as $\bigcup [n_i]$

If this is a finite union, then $\bigcup [n_i] = [max\{n_1,...n_k\}]$, hence open.

If this is a infinite union, then $ \bigcup [n_i] = \mathbb{N}$, hence open.

Why? $ \bigcup [n_i] \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ no doubt, and, $\mathbb{N}\subseteq  \bigcup [n_i]$ because $n_i$'s are different, we have ordering going $n_1<n_2<....$, note $1\le n_1, 2\le n_2,...$, so if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n< n_m$ then $n\in [n_m] \subseteq \bigcup [n_i]$.

P.S. hello MA 564 people